# Unclear Architecture of MNIST Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, convolution

I am trying to reproduce a Neural Network trained to detect whether there is a 0-3 digit in an image with another confounding image. The paper I am following lists the corresponding architecture:

A neural network with 28×56 input neurons and one output neuron is trained on this task. The input values are coded between −0.5 (black) and +1.5 (white). The neural network is composed of a first detection pooling layer with 400 detection neurons sum-pooled into 100 units (i.e. we sum-pool non-overlapping groups of 4 detection units). A second detection-pooling layer with 400 detection neurons is applied to the 100-dimensional output of the previous layer, and activities are sum-pooled onto a single unit representing the deep network output. Positive examples (0-3 digit in the image) are assigned target value 100 and negative examples are assigned target value 0. The neural network is trained to minimizethe mean-square error between the target values and its output.

My main doubt is in this context what they mean by detection neurons, if they mean filters or a single standard ReLU neuron. Also, if the mean filters, how could they be applied in the second layer to a 100-dimensional output when they are designed to operate on 2x2 matrixes.

Montavon, G., Bach, S., Binder, A., Samek, W., & Müller, K. (2015). Explaining NonLinear Classification Decisions with Deep Taylor Decomposition. arXiv. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.patcog.2016.11.008. Specifically section 4.C

Comment: Could you please give a citation for the paper (full citation, such as from Google Scholar, not just a link)?

Comment: Here you go: Montavon, G., Bach, S., Binder, A., Samek, W., & Müller, K. (2015). Explaining NonLinear Classification Decisions with Deep Taylor Decomposition. arXiv. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.patcog.2016.11.008. Specifically section 4.C